# Create group with same name in different OU

Tags: server, active-directory

I am trying to create group with same name in Different OU however it is showing the group is already existed with same name.

is there way to create group with same name in Different OUs ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean by "name".

The `name` and `cn` attributes always have the same values, and are what appear in the `distinguishedName`. You *can* have two objects with the same `name` or `cn` in different OUs. For example:

```
CN=GroupName,OU=FirstOU,DC=example,DC=com
CN=GroupName,OU=SecondOU,DC=example,DC=com
```

However, the `sAMAccountName` is different, and it must be unique across the whole domain. So if you create two groups with the same `name`, the `sAMAccountName` still must be different.

The `displayName` is something else too. For groups, this only really matters for distributions lists, and it is the name that would appear in Outlook, for example. There are no uniqueness constraints on `displayName`. You can have two with the same `displayName` even in the same OU.

Comment: OK. So I will have keep sAMAccountName Different ?

Comment: That's correct.